# Test Angular controller calls service function exactly once using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following...

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function(testService){
   testService.doSomething();
});
app.service('testService', function(){
   this.doSomething = function(){...};
});
```

I want to use Jasmine to ensure doSomething is called once and only once. I seem to be having some trouble doing this.

Also, I am currently grabbing my controller from a compiled element like this...

```
var element = angular.element('<my-test-directive />');
controller = view.controller('testCtrl');
```

So extra appreciation if it fits with this sort of formatting

**Update**

I tried this...

```
describe("Testing", function () {
  var $rootScope,
    $scope,
    $compile,
    testService,
    view,
    $controller;
  beforeEach(module("app"));
  function createController() {
    return $controller('testCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        testService:testService
    });

  }
  function SetUpScope(_$controller_,  _$compile_, _$rootScope_, _testService_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
    testService = _testService_;
    spyOn(testService, 'doSomething');
  }
  SetUpScope.$inject = ["$controller","$compile", "$rootScope", "testService"];
  beforeEach(inject(SetUpScope));
  it("On intitialization, the controller should register itself with the list service", function(done){
    createController();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(workOrderService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

It seems to work

Comment: see my update with working plunkr

Comment: I added exactly one call expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably better to test controller in isolation and use Jasmine spies for this:

```
spyOn(testService, 'doSomething');
expect(testService.doSomething.calls.count()).toEqual(0);
```

Something like this should work in the actual test.

```
describe('testCtrl function', function() {

  describe('testCtrl', function() {
    var $scope, testService;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _testService_) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      testService = _testService_;
      spyOn(testService, 'doSomething');
      $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});
    }));

    it('should call testService.doSomething()', function() {
      expect(testService.doSomething.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is a quick plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Swso4Y

Depending on which version of Jasmine you are using you might need to use

```
expect(testService.doSomething.calls.length).toEqual(1);
```